# Switch to Xcode 8 beta?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistackview

I'm running Xcode 7.3.1 on a MBP with OS X 10.11.3.

I started using UIStackViews to help me lay out my UI. The first experiment went fine--made a great custom number pad with it. So I moved to a slightly more complex scene, and once I started nesting stack views, Xcode slowed to a crawl. With every command, it waits 5 seconds, then beachballs for 10 before executing it. Infuriating. I've restarted Xcode multiple times, but no improvement. And I see a number of people have reported this bug to Apple.

I see the beta for Xcode 8 is available, and have read a few comments, but haven't found any directly relating to an improvement in the performance of stack views.

Can anyone recommend the beta as a better choice than my current version based on their experience with stack view performance in Xcode 8 beta?

Comment: How did you start messing with stack views prior to iOS 9?

Comment: I'm writing for iOS 9...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should never fully switch to a beta version of Xcode. Apple doesn't yet allow you to submit to the App Store using Xcode 8, and probably won't for some time yet.

Early betas also tend to be full of bugs, rough edges, and performance bottlenecks. In fact, early x.0 `RELEASE` versions of Xcode tend to be buggy as hell. I wish Apple would slow down their mad rush to add new features and spend time stabilizing the current build tool, but I doubt if I'm going to get my wish.

By all means download Xcode 8 and experiment with it, but don't get rid of 7.3 until after Xcode 8 goes GM, and maybe not even then.

### EDIT:

Now that the Xcode 8 GM candidate has been released it's reasonable to start using for production work, but I would still keep a copy of Xcode 7.x around for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I'm with you on the constant new releases that seem to fix stuff I'm not interested in and leave mainstream issues broken! I'll take your suggestion, and thanks!

Comment: So what about the workflow ? Should we work on two branches then ? One on swift 3 (and xcode 8), and one on swift 2 (xcode 7.3). Thanks for the precisions about the release

Comment: I don't have an easy answer for you. If your release date is out far enough, use Swift 3. Otherwise, you probably need to stick with Swift 2 for now since you won't be able to release until Apple allows Xcode 8 apps onto the App Store.

Comment: Xcode 8 GM seed is still buggy like its latest Beta, serious bug on UIView embedded into a ScrollView, the Storyboard messes it up every time you open your project, it doesn't matter if you fixed the size of that View once, you have to do that all over again once you reopen the project.

Answer (score 0):

Beta versions of XCode have usually lots of bugs, we've currently tried beta 6 and noticed that it messes up with views into a ScrollView in the Storyboard, so we just got rid of it.

We'll be waiting for the official version of Xcode to be available before switching from 7.3 to 8, and we suggest you to do the same.

Comment: Scrollview problems fixed in GM?

Comment: unfortunately no :(